# Linq Query with a where condition - count items

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can I change this request :

```
query = query.Where(item => (from table in context.Table 
                             where table.amount == item.Amount 
                             select table).Count() >= 10);
```

to not use the subquery `(from ... in ...)` ?

I tried to create the subquery separately, to use it with the Where condition :

> var subQuery = from table in context.Table select table.amount;
>
> var list = subQuery.ToList()

But I don't know how I can use it after that, because of the `.Count()` operation.

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: What is `query` in the first statement ?

Comment: @Habib: I assume you are trying to understand if this is Linq to objects, SQL, etc.?

Comment: I am not sure about Count() but other Linq methods take an expression so you could potentially do query.Where(item => context.Table.Count(a => a.amount == item.Amount);

Comment: @Chris, its not about linq to objects.  Based on the information given, the only correct answers are the ones that are given.  If however we understood how `query` was created, we could see how to better merge your subselect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
query = query.Where(item => context.Table
                                   .Count(t => t.amount == item.Amount) >= 10);
```

Or to reduce the number of round-trips:

```
var counts = context.Table
                    .GroupBy(t => t.amount)
                    .Select(g => new {amount = g.Key, count = g.Count()});

query = from q in query
        join c in counts
        on q.amount equals c.amount
        where c.count >= 10
        select q;
```

Comment: Is that not using a subquery still? In fact isn't that exactly the same as the original except using method syntax instead of query syntax (or whatever the other one is called)?

Comment: I think you'll have to use `on q.Amount equals c.amount` for the join

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Count` with a predicate directly:

```
query.Where(item => context.Table.Count(table.amount == item.Amount) >= 10);
```

Comment: Is that not using a subquery still? In fact isn't that exactly the same as the original except using method syntax instead of query syntax (or whatever the other one is called)?

Answer (score 0):

what about this one

```
var subQuery = (from table in context.Table select table.amount).ToList();

query = query.Where(item => subQuery.Count() >= 10);
```

Comment: Still wrong. You just check if there are more than ten elements in `context.Table`, for each element in `query`. So you either get all elements in `query`, or none.